# how to know if the java completes its process in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am doing a ajax call which in turns call the java and process the request there.
i am facing problem that ajax sends the request and continue to work on the rest of the part without any knowledge of whether the java process is complete is not, i want after java completes all process i want to click a button which is already present in the ui.
i tried

```
req.open("GET", url, true);        req.send(null);
if (req.readyState == 4) 
{ 

if (req.status == 200) 
        {

 //click a button
        } 

  else
        {

 }
    }
    }
```

but it always showing ready state is 1

Please help

Comment: I think you should first learn ajax before asking this question. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: u can use .ajaxStart() and .ajaxComplete()

Comment: You did not use proper AJAX

Comment: Use an `onreadystatechange` event handler. @BilalZafar - No "jQuery" tag on the question. @kernallora - what do you think "ajax" is if not making an http request from JS?

Comment: It's my bad sorry

Answer (score 0):

You should try proper approach, just try like this.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
```

Comment: this i am doing..i only posted the part which i changed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227020/how-to-hit-a-button-in-ajax-to-java-call please see this post

Answer (score 0):

You could use two paradigm:

request/response of HTTP (done using ajax) or using socket.

A WebSocket (for web) defines an API for "socket" connections between a web browser and a server (where your process is running).

When using WebSocket a persistent connection between your client and the server is established and both parties can start sending data at any time to each other.