# how to hit a button in ajax to java call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have written below code

```
var req;
var isIE;

function init() {
    completeField = document.getElementById("complete-field");
}

function doCompletion() {
        var url = "autocomplete?action=complete&id=" + escape(completeField.value);
        req = initRequest();
        req.open("GET", url, true);
        req.onreadystatechange = callback;
        req.send(null);
}

function initRequest() {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1) {
            isIE = true;
        }
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        isIE = true;
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
}
```

and the callback function :

```
function callback() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("IDVALUE").click();
        }
    }
}
```

i am debugging i can see IDVALUE button is getting clicked and its working fine.
But without debugging that button is not getting clicked.

Basically in ajax to java call...i am updating some fields in database and when all the process completes in java side.i need to hit the apply button in the ui again, so that it will fetch the latest data from db.

help!!

Comment: Seems to be fine... Once can you try put onreadystatechange  in settimeout function?

Comment: tried..not working

Comment: You mentioned while debugging it is working??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use  fireEvent() method of javascript for trigger event.

```
 document.getElementById("IDVALUE").fireEvent("onclick");
```

Comment: It doesn't work...also the alert('') is not not working in that place